# Getting the row and column of active cell doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script in google Spreadsheet, which gets the active cell and then the row and column of the active cell:

```
function editedCellResponse() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var r = s.getRow(); // gets row of edited cell
  var c = s.getColumn(); // gets column of edited cell
  ... script then goes on doing what ever

}
```

This script also has an onEdit trigger so it's triggered at each edit of the spreadsheet. However either the getActiveCell doesn't work or the getRow and getColumn don't work because the (row, column) result is always (1, 1) regardless of the active cell. The funny thing is as I was first writing the script this all worked and I never changed anything, but now all of a sudden nothing works because the script seems to be reading the active cell or row and column wrong.

Any ideas as to what might be wrong?

Comment: if your function is runned in a `onEdit` trigger, then there is no active cell, that's why it always return `1, 1`. You need to acces the range in the `onEdit event`

Comment: @LioraHaydont the funny thing is that at does also work without the event of the onEdit function, just not always. For example, when I was writing this post, the code didn't work. The next day, I ran it again, the code was unchanged, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e){ 
  var r = e.range.getRow(); 
  var c = e.range.getColumn();
  Logger.log('%s,%s',r,c);
}
```

Comment: If the problem persists, I will eventually change the code to include the event. I tried to avoid that just for the purpose of easier debugging. The funny thing is that at does also work without the event of the onEdit function, just not always. For example, when I was writing this post, the code didn't work. The next day, I ran it again, the code was unchanged, and it worked fine.

Comment: You could rename the function with something like on3dit(e) and call it from another function like teston3dit() Inside the test function you could create the var e={range:v} and call it from inside a loop that feeds v different range values. Normally I don’t do this because in the end it has to work with trigger event and it’s easier to just make edits on a spreadsheet. By the way, is this sheet a form response sheet? If it is you my need to use lock service to keep onFormSubmits from interacting with you onEdit events.